# Cointegration Test: Residual is stationary but not random?

Tags: cointegration, pairs-trading, auto-correlation

I am testing cointegration relationship on various pairs of stocks by this following these steps.

1. Test for I(1) on a pair of stocks, says X and Y, using Dickey-Fuller test. If both time series are non-stationary, I continue to step 2.
2. Run long-run (equilibrium) equation of stock Y on X, estimate parameters and collect residuals.
3. Test for unit root of that residual series using same method in step 1.
   For many pairs I have tested, the tests reject null hypothesis that there is a unit root, implying valid cointegration relationship. (regression on  $\Delta \epsilon = \alpha*\epsilon_{t-1} + u_t$ then compare test statistic ($\alpha$/S.E. of estimated $\alpha$) with critical value (from Dickey Fuller's Table, I presume) )

**Now, here is my problem. After I finished all that stuffs I try plotting residual series and, clearly, it is not random. Residual looks correlated! 
It looks like this.**

[image: Residual Plot]
...

My questions:

1. Is it safe to conclude that the pair is cointegrated just because the residual is stationary and dont care that the residual is not random?
2. Can I continue with the result that the pairs are cointegrated and continue to do pair trading if I want to or I just have to continue to estimate the Error Correction Model in order to complete Engle-Granger 2 step procedure?**
3. Which critical value table should I use in step 1 and step 3? I think I should use Dickey Fuller's Table for step 1 as the test is done over the residual term rather than raw data, it is not possible to use standard t-distribution table. For step 3, Im not sure because the test is done over the **estimated** residual term.

Please bear with me..., there is more

According to this paper, on page 6, http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/gboero/personal/hand2_cointeg.pdf

it says if I test residual for stationary on 
$$
Y_t = \alpha + \beta_0*X_t + \beta_1*X_{t-1} + C*Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, 
$$
**this will prevent the bias due to serial correlation** on traditional regression ($y_t = \alpha + \beta_0*x_t + \epsilon_t$). I assume that I will use the same stationary test as in step 3 above.

4. Which critical value table should I use for stationary test written in the paper I have shown? Currently, I've got very high test statistic, over 14. I suspect I have done it wrong.

Any contribution will be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jack, I applied some tex to the question. But to the content: why do you say that your residual is not random? Is it deterministic? If not then it is random. Or do you mean that it looks a bit periodic? The notion of stationarity is interesting in the context of random processes only. So how can it be stationary but not random?